# PHP For Each Append Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Example code array: https://eval.in/639002

A guest with (user_id = 1) bought multiple tickets (ticket_id = 1 & 2) On event (event_id = 11).

I am expecting the result format:

```
[ticket] => Array
(
  [1] => Ticket Name, ***
  [2] => Ticket Name
)
```

Code example below:

```
$data_db = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'user_id' => 1,
        'event_id' => 11,
        'ticket_id' => 1,
        'user_name' => 'guest 1'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'user_id' => 2,
        'event_id' => 11,
        'ticket_id' => 1,
        'user_name' => 'guest 2'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'user_id' => 3,
        'event_id' => 22,
        'ticket_id' => 1,
        'user_name' => 'guest 3'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'user_id' => 1,
        'event_id' => 11,
        'ticket_id' => 2,
        'user_name' => 'guest 1'
    )
);

$output = [];

foreach ( $data_db as $key => $row ) {

    $output[ $row['event_id'] ]['event'] = 'Event Name';    
    $output[ $row['event_id'] ]['attendee'][ $row['user_id'] ] = $row;

    $output[ $row['event_id'] ]['attendee'][ $row['user_id'] ]['ticket'][ $row['ticket_id'] ] = 'Ticket Name';

}

print_r($output);
```

Current result

```
Array
(
    [11] => Array
        (
            [event] => Event Name
            [attendee] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [user_id] => 1
                            [event_id] => 11
                            [ticket_id] => 2
                            [user_name] => guest 1
                            [ticket] => Array
                                (
                                    [2] => Ticket Name
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [user_id] => 2
                            [event_id] => 11
                            [ticket_id] => 1
                            [user_name] => guest 2
                            [ticket] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => Ticket Name ***
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [event] => Event Name
            [attendee] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [user_id] => 3
                            [event_id] => 22
                            [ticket_id] => 1
                            [user_name] => guest 3
                            [ticket] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => Ticket Name
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: pls give example, what type of output array you want.

Answer (score 0):

First of you could start by sorting out an array of tickets of which ticket belongs to which user:

```
$output = [];

foreach($data_db as $key=>$row) {
  // Define new $tickets Array E.g ['guest_name']=>['ticket_id']
  $tickets[$row['user_name']][] = $row['ticket_id'];
  $output [] = [
               'id'=>$row['id'], 
               'user_id'=>$row['user_id'], 
               'event_id'=>$row['event_id'], 
               'user_name'=>$row['user_name'],
               'tickets'=>[]
              ];
}
```

Your output of $tickets would look like:

```
Array
(
    [guest 1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )
    [guest 2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )
    [guest 3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )
)
```

Then you can combine them, like this:

```
foreach($output as $k=>$v){
 foreach($tickets as $guest=>$ticket){

    if($v['user_name'] == $guest){
      $output[$k]['tickets'] = $ticket;
    }

  }
}
```

Your output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [user_id] => 1
            [event_id] => 11
            [user_name] => guest 1
            [tickets] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [user_id] => 2
            [event_id] => 11
            [user_name] => guest 2
            [tickets] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )
              ........
```